# Execute command as long as user hold arrow keyboard?

Tags: javascript, php

I have client device that connected to my router (my router running with openwrt, debian based linux). So basicly the device will turn on DC motor if i send/echo "F" character. 
That job is done by using php file with this command

```
shell_exec('echo "F" > /dev/ttyACM0')
```

How do i change that code (similar concept) by javascript?
So when i press UP arrow keyboard button, it will echoing "F" character as long as I holding it. When i release UP arrow keyboard button, it will stop echoing the character.
Thankyou

Comment: keep the php file as it is and perform an asyncronous call. Alternatively, use a real-time library such as nodejs. Currently, the fastest (but non brilliant) you can do is perform an **asyncronous HTTP request** from your javascript to your php script. Get the request from the php script, elaborate it and execute your command, then return success or error from PHP to your javascript script.

Comment: I've added my answer, let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using jquery like this.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(document).keydown(function(e) {

            if(e.which == 38) {
                $("#result_box").html('>> F ');
            }
        });

        $(document).keyup(function(e) {

            if(e.which == 38)
                $("#result_box").html('>> F ');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML for displaying result

```
<div id="result_box"></div>
```

Let me know if it helps you